# Is there a hand-writing recognition input method on Linux for use with a stylus?

Tags: handwriting

I have a Linux touch-screen laptop, and thought it could be good practice to write Hangul using the touch-screen with a stylus, and have that translated as text. Firstly, that would be a good way for me to interact with online Korean communities (such as this one) while learning Korean, and if the input-recognition is good enough, it would also be useful for training myself to write Korean, I imagine.

However, a quick search did not turn up anything extremely promising (compared to say, what is available for Android and Chromebooks), but I thought I'd ask around.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with using it online, I would suggest giving Naver's online translate tool's handwriting recognition a try

I don't have a touch screen nor linux computer at hand, but this works completely in a browser so I am hoping it is OS independent

A quick test on Chrome in Windows seems to work quite good:

[image]

Go to https://papago.naver.com/ and click on the handwriting button.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, an online option would be ok most of the time. When I try this, I click on the writing tool and get a draggable "window" within the page, but whenever I write anything, or even click translate, I don't see the recognized Korean text pop up like you have.

Comment: @bbarker share a screenshot or screen capture video if possible. Are you using chrome?

Comment: Yes, this was on Chrome (in Windows 10 - just trying it out). I uploaded a screencast, though oddly the screencast itself didn't work in Chrome, I did have luck in Firefox: https://www.screencast.com/t/xfqToqNzMZL

Comment: Ah, if you click on Details in the top right, then you can see a download button, and view the screencast in a video player outside of the browser.

Comment: I've sent a message including a link to your video to Naver, I'll update here if they reply. Does that video auto delete after sometime or does it stay there? The video keeps crashing for me, if possible see if you can fix that.

Comment: Sure, I went ahead and uploaded to youtube, hopefully that is easier: https://youtu.be/bvDPOLMjzXg Thanks again!